# Django - can not publish post

Tags: python, django

I have a problem, I'm just making a simple blog. I wanted to have possibility to save my posts as a drafts before I publish them. 
I follow step by step video, I have almost everything same and there is still some problem - publish function doesn't work.
Do you have some ideas why?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    autor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tytuł = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    tekst = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py(that function)

```
@login_required
def post_publish(request, pk):

    post = get_object_or_404(models.Post, pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk)
```

and if statement in html file:

```
{% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date postdate">
              {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
{% else %}
           <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
                path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
                path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name="about"),
                path('posts/', views.PostListView.as_view(), name="post_list"),
                re_path(r'posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post_detail"),
                path('posts/new/', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name="post_new"),
                re_path(r'posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post_edit"),
                re_path(r'posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/', views.PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="post_remove"),
                path('drafts/', views.DraftListView.as_view(), name="post_draft_list"),
                re_path(r'posts/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/', views.post_publish, name="post_publish")
                ]
```

Everything is good as far as I don't click "publish". It does nothing

Comment: Can you show us the error logs?

Comment: I don't get any errors, just nothing is hapenning

Comment: Does the link on your button work? You can inspect it and post it here. Are you using an ide? When using PyCharm you could run debugger and step through the events.

Comment: It does, in the meantime I solved that problem. I changed all regular expressions in urls for <int:pk> and it just started working, but still have no idea why